# Handle multiple ajax requests works only when alerted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-nestable

I'm trying to send data to server from many lists in a page, each firing ajax data for PHP to process further. My code selects each lists using (class=dd) and send ajax data one by one. This works perfectly when I use alert(response) after ajax success, removing this alert message only sends less number of lists to server(only 2 lists are sent out of 4). Any thoughts?

```
 $('#submit_sorting').on('click', function() {
        var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (testEmail.test($('#user_email').val()) || $('#user_email').val()==""){
            $('[class=dd]').each(function(){
                     var data = $(this).nestable('serialize');
                     var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);
                     console.log('sent '+JSON.stringify(data));
                     var response = ajaxx(data);
                     alert(response);
                });  
        }
        else
        {
            alert('enter valid email address');
        }

    });
```

and here is the ajax code

```
  function ajaxx(data){
          return $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
             url: 'cardsorting/update',
            data: {
                'new_order': data,
                'user_comments':$('#user_comments').val(),
                'user_email':$('#user_email').val(),
                '_token':$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }, 
           success: function(data){
              if(data=='dataissaved'){
                  console.log('came here '+$(location).attr('href'));
              }
             else
             {
                  console.log('received '+JSON.stringify(data));

              }

        },
           error: function (data) {
                alert('Could not connect to controller');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: try this  $.ajax({
    ...
    async: false
});

Comment: $.ajax is asynchronous ... learn how to code asynchronous code, whose to say `async:false` will always work, it has been deprecated in firefox and chrome for months now

Comment: Why did not you send all the data in array and process in the "cardsorting/update" handler ?

Answer (score 0):

Here how it worked in the end, instead of sending multiple ajax requests for each selection, I collect them in an array and then ajax it to the backend php.

```
$('#submit_sorting').on('click', function() {
    var sorting_array = new Array();
    var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var flag = false;
    if (testEmail.test($('#user_email').val()) || $('#user_email').val()==""){
           $('[class=dd]').each(function(){
                 var data = $(this).nestable('serialize');
                 sorting_array.push(data);
                 console.log('sent '+JSON.stringify(data));               
            }); 
            flag = true;
        }
    else
    {
        alert('enter valid email address');
    }
    if(flag){
        ajaxx(sorting_array);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(sorting_array)); 
    }

});
```